# How to use read command with question and variable alltogether?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-formatting

How can I use read command to be able to use colors in part of the text and variable in it without using --dialog command in linux shell script?

Example I need a question to appear like this in bash script:

Is this version ok?: *1.0.1* (number is in green color)

My try so far:

```
Version=1.0.1
textGreen='\e[1;92m' # Green
noColor='\033[0m' # No color
read -p "Is this version ok?: ${textGreen} ${Version} ${noColor} (y/n)" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
...
```

This does not work it shows variable and not the number and no color at all.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color codes are alright, I'm just not sure whether read supports colored output.

I split your read in two commands, one to print the question and one to receive the answer:

```
Version=1.0.1
textGreen='\e[92m'
noColor='\e[0m'
echo -e "Is this version ok?: ${textGreen}${Version}${noColor} (y/n)"
stty raw
REPLY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null)
stty -raw
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
...
```

echo supports colored output with the -e option. I'm now using a little hack to catch one character of raw input from the terminal prompt.

Comment: It is not working actually - color is ok but the answer will not get it... When I press Y or y it does not proceed

Comment: I changed the code to read just one character, instead of a whole line.

Comment: Why change the `read` call to something so complex? The problem isn't with the `read` call.

Answer (score 3):

You're telling `read` to display a prompt that contains backslash e bracket etc. so it displays a prompt that contains backslash e bracket etc. Pass it a prompt string that contains actual escape characters. The easiest way to do that is with [dollar-quote quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

```
textGreen=$'\e[1;92m' # Green
noColor=$'\033[0m' # No color
```

Comment: This way will still not work the variable ... - variable will not display number but the name of the variable.

Comment: @Byakugan It does work, unless you've changed something else. Keep the line that calls `read` the way it is in the question.

Comment: Will this work in echo -e "${textGreen}Text" with these escape characters?

Comment: @Byakugan Yes, but you don't need the `-e`. Both `echo -e` and `$'…'` convert backslash escapes to control characters. The advantage of `$'…'` is that it lets you use the string for anything, whereas `echo -e` only prints the result.